# Cada vez que se pulsa en un botón, se vuelve a llamar a la misma función para reordenar de manera aleatoria un array en react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
<div className=" row pt-3 pr-3 pl-3 ">  { 
        shuffleArray(array).map((respuestasv)=>(
            <div key={respuestasv.id} className="col-md-6  ">
                <button type="button" 
                    onClick={(e) =>handleClickedVideo(e,respuestasv)}
                    className="btn btn-block btn-light btn-sm mb-4"
                    >{respuestasv.name } </button>
            </div>
        ))}
```

Código de `shuffleArray(a)`

```
function shuffleArray(a) {
     console.log("hi")
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

En mi react.js tengo un array de datos que traigo de un api y este quiero que sea reordenado aleatoriamente con el código anterior. Para ello cuento con una funcion `shuffleArray(a)` pero surge un problema que no lo entiendo:

Que cada vez que hago click en el botón, este llama de nuevo a `shuffleArray` y me reorganiza el array haciendo que se muestre los datos en diferente orden nuevamente. El comportamiento esperado es que se muestre el array desordenado que paso por `shufleArray`, y cuando clickee (el click se da una sola vez) sea este mismo array y que no llame otra vez a `shufleArray`.

`Entendí que se esta haciendo un re-render por el método shuffleArray(a) por que este cambia el valor de **a** por el valor aleatorio de **a** por lo que lo vuelve a renderizar.`
¿Cómo podría evitas ese comportamiento?.

Comment: Parece que se esta haciendo un re-render en `handleClickedVideo`, por esa razón `shuffleArray` se dispara nuevamente y con su respectivo nuevo ordenamiento, puede que se tenga que rediseñar la lógica de `suffleArray`, ¿Puedes compartir el código de `handleClickedVideo`?

Comment: handleClickedVideo  tenia bastante código pero ahora lo borre todo y sigue pasando lo mismo. luego le puse event.preventDefault() y sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Entendí que se esta haciendo un re-render por el método shuffleArray(a) por que este cambia el valor de **a** por el valor aleatorio de **a** por lo que lo vuelve a renderizar. ¿Cómo podría evitas ese comportamiento?

Por lo que mencionas, el array que proviene de la API siempre es el mismo; pero no quieres que se cambie el orden de este en cada llamada a `handleClickedVideo`, si no solo al iniciar el componente.

Suponiendo que el ejemplo que nos compartes presenta el siguiente comportamiento (emulación con Post API):

```js
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
  const [rerender, setRerender] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setPosts(data));
  }, []);


  function shuffleArray(a) {
    //console.log("hi")
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
  }

  function handleClickedVideo(a,b){
    let totalErrors=[];
    //console.log("in vid");
    totalErrors.push({"error":"cuatro"})
    setRerender(totalErrors);
  }

  return (
    <div>
        {shuffleArray(posts).map((respuestasv)=>(
            <div key={respuestasv.id}>
                <button type="button" 
                    onClick={(e) =>handleClickedVideo(e,respuestasv)}
                    >{respuestasv.title } </button>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

#### useMemo

Se puede usar el hook `useMemo`, esto con la finalidad de regresar el `array` memorizado, este no va a cambiar su valor en memoria, si no **hasta que la dependencia que se indique cambie su valor**. Se puede hacer uso de este hook pues como ya se mencionó, el `array` que proviene de la API siempre es el mismo; y este `array` se puede usar como la dependencia de `useMemo`.

Implementando `useMemo`:

```js
function App() {
      const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
      const [rerender, setRerender] = React.useState(false);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => setPosts(data));
      }, []);


      function shuffleArray(a) {
        //console.log("hi")
        var j, x, i;
        for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            x = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = x;
        }
        return a;
      }
      
      const memoShuffleArray = React.useMemo(()=>{
          let a = shuffleArray(posts)
          return ()=> a;
        },[posts]
      );

      function handleClickedVideo(a,b){
        let totalErrors=[];
        //console.log("in vid");
        totalErrors.push({"error":"cuatro"})
        setRerender(totalErrors);
      }

      return (
        <div>
            {memoShuffleArray().map((respuestasv)=>(
                <div key={respuestasv.id}>
                    <button type="button" 
                        onClick={(e) =>handleClickedVideo(e,respuestasv)}
                        >{respuestasv.title } </button>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      );
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

[Hook useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)