# Cada vez que se pulsa en un botón renderizado por map, se renderiza de nuevo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux, react-redux

```
function shuffleArray(a) {
     console.log("hi")
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
    return a;
}
```

```
/*En esta parte tengo un condicional que cuando este cargado las preguntas y 
 tenga mi variable evolución en  verdadero recién se muestre*/
<div className=" row pt-3 pr-3 pl-3 ">  { 
        shuffleArray(array).map((respuestasv)=>(
            <div key={respuestasv.id} className="col-md-6  ">
                <button type="button" 
                    onClick={(e) =>handleNextEvo(e,respuestasv)}
                    className="btn btn-block btn-light btn-sm mb-4"
                    >{respuestasv.name } </button>
            </div>
        ))}
```

```
const handleNextEvo = () => {
    if(ev.corregidomsg!=''){
       dispatch(SetearModalContinuar());
        }else{
            if (ev.preguntas[0].length<=1) {
              handleTerminarEvo();
            }else{
          const cambiarorden=[];
          cambiarorden[0]=ev.preguntas[0];
          cambiarorden[0].splice(ev.preguntanro, 1);
          dispatch(CambiarOrdenPreguntaError(cambiarorden));
            }
        }
        dispatch(SetearDefaultEvo());
      }
```

```
const memoShuffleArray = React.useMemo(()=>{
          let a = shuffleArray(posts)
          return ()=> a;
        },[posts]
      );
```

En mi react.js tengo un array de datos que traigo de un api de esta forma[image: Datos del Api]  y este quiero que sea reordenado las respuestas  aleatoriamente con el código anterior. Para ello cuento con una funcion shuffleArray(a) pero surge un problema .

Que cada vez que hago click en el botón, este llama de nuevo a shuffleArray y me reorganiza el array haciendo que se muestre los datos en diferente orden nuevamente. El comportamiento esperado es que se muestre el array desordenado que paso por shufleArray, y cuando clickee (el click se da una sola vez) sea este mismo array y que no llame otra vez a shufleArray.

> Entendí que se esta haciendo un re-render por el método shuffleArray(a) por que este cambia el valor de **a** por el valor aleatorio de **a** por lo que lo vuelve a renderizar. Lo logre solucionar con ayuda del foro con el hook useMemo [click para llegar a la solución anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463389/cada-vez-que-se-pulsa-en-un-bot%C3%B3n-se-vuelve-a-llamar-a-la-misma-funci%C3%B3n-para-re) cuando la aplicación solo usaba react pero ahora estoy usando react con redux y la situación se me complico.
> ¿Cómo haría que se ordene aleatoriamente y que este no cambie el orden a pesar de ser ordenado cuando se hace click?

```
<button type="button" onClick={()=>{EvolucionarPreguntas()}}    
className="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-sm mb-2 mt-2 ">
Comenzar Evolución
</button>
```

```
const EvolucionarPreguntas = () => {
            dispatch(EvolucionTrue());//manda a cambiar la variable del reducer que por defecto estaba en falso a verdadero

            dispatch(fetchPreguntasEvolucion(subtemaid,nivel));
    }
```

Redux-Action

```
export const fetchPreguntasEvolucionRequestAction = () => {
    return{
        type    :FETCH_PREGUNTAS_EVOLUCION_REQUEST
    }
}
export const fetchPreguntasEvolucionSuccessAction = (url) =>{
    return{
        type    :FETCH_PREGUNTAS_EVOLUCION_SUCCESS,
        payload :url
    }
}
export const fetchPreguntasEvolucionFailureAction = (error) =>{
    return{
        type    : FETCH_PREGUNTAS_EVOLUCION_FAILURE,
        payload : error
    }
}
export const fetchPreguntasEvolucion = (subtemaid,nivel) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchPreguntasEvolucionRequestAction());
         api.get(`api/problemasevo/${subtemaid}/nivel/${nivel}`)
            .then( response => {
                dispatch(fetchPreguntasEvolucionSuccessAction([response.data]));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchPreguntasEvolucionFailureAction('el servidor no responde'));
            });
    }
}
```

REDUX-REDUCER

```
case FETCH_PREGUNTAS_EVOLUCION_REQUEST :
            return {
                ...state,
                loading : true
            }
        case FETCH_PREGUNTAS_EVOLUCION_SUCCESS :
            return {
                ...state,
                loading      : false,
                preguntas    : action.payload,
                error        : ''
            }
         case FETCH_PREGUNTAS_EVOLUCION_FAILURE :
            return {
                ... state,
                loading : false,
                preguntas     : [],
                error   : action.payload
            }
```

Comment: Interesante, ¿Estas obteniendo el estado `array` desde redux con `useSelector`? ¿O como lo estas obteniendo/trayendo en tu componente? Saludos

Comment: Si estoy usando useSelector.

Comment: ¿Puedes agrergar el `useEffect` donde llamas a la función `thunk` que carga el `array`?

Comment: cuando cargo las respuestas no uso useEffect lo llamo al hacer click en comenzar evaluación que llama al thunk.

Comment: Estoy tratando de reproducir el problema, si pudieras agregar esa pieza de código, como llamas al `array`.

Comment: la parte donde tengo mis respuestas esta bajo condicional que recién se muestra cuando coloco la variable a true y tenga datos del API. La condicional la seteo a true cuando hago click en comenzar evolución. Y agregue la llamada de mi api.

Comment: Y los datos los acabo de colocar en este jsonstore. [enlace]https://api.jsonbin.io/b/611c910f076a223676ad31ed @g.4

Comment: No pude emular el escenario de mi lado, pero intenta lo siguiente: En el dependency array de `useMemo`, coloca la longitud de posts, es decir así `const memoShuffleArray = useMemo(()=>{...},[posts.length]);`, por favor avísame del resultado, saludos

Comment: @g.4 revise el código haciéndolo lo mas sencillo posible y descubrí que el useMemo no estaba trabajando. Reinicie todo y actualice con npm y todo volvió a funcionar como cuando solo estaba usando Redux. Gracias por la ayuda. Si no es demasiado quisiera que veas mi código de react en general.

Comment: Tu código se ve bastante bien a mi parecer, pienso que el problema de porque se sigue disparando la función `shuffle` se debe a la referencia `post`, en la pregunta pasada el dueño del estado era el componente padre, de ahí podíamos programar cuando cambiara la referencia `post`; la referencia no cambiaba al hacer el `handle` y por eso `useMemo`, funcionaba y memorizaba el valor de `post`

Comment: Pero ahora el dueño del estado es redux, entonces por ahí al hacer click en el handle, seguramente la referencia de `post` si cambia dentro de algún dispatch al redux store, por ende ya no ves el efecto de memoization, pues `useMemo` ya no trabaja (ya no memoriza, se dispara otra vez). Lo que sugiero es que pases todo el código de la operación de shuffle a un `dispatch action` y hagas pruebas.

Comment: Pero lo bueno es que lograste avanzar como mencionas, al reiniciar todo. Si tienes un repo y aun quieres explorar lo de useMemo, pásame la liga para tratar de apoyarte desde ahí, porque no es fácil debuguear desde aquí, saludos